# Problem to select multiple objects in in sculptmode in 2.91

Tags: sculpting

In 2.91 from 25st of Sept and onwards you are supposed to select multiple objects in sculpt mode by hovering with mouse and push D. It's simply not working for me and I need this feature. What am I doing wrong and am I the only one having this problem?

//Erik

Comment: it does not allow to select multiple objects, it allows to switch from an object to another, and you need to enable this option because it is still experimental: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mkj338ytNPQ#t=17m

Comment: I meant switch objects. Where do I enable the option? It is not found in the video

Comment: in the Preferences > Interface > Display > Developer Extras, then there's a Experimental button in the left column, it may be there?

Comment: You made my day! Big thanks! It would be good if Youtubers could add this info

Comment: well it's a brand new feature, it's still in test